# Bootstrap Modal popup shows on clicking back button in html/css

Tags: css, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a popup to show zoomed text .In the modal popup even if i close the box , on clicking back button in my browser the modal is getting displayed again. Is there any way to permanently close the box ??? Below is my code.. TIA :)

```
        <a href="#openModal" class="test">Zoom Text</a>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <p class="test">Test</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#close" class="button">Close</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the "Back" browser button triggers displaying page(s ) from history of browsing. You can ensure that when this action takes place, your modal will be forcibly closed by executing some sort of changing display mode of the `div` with JavaScript and usage of [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) event. Something like this code snippet:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
 window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){
    // .... Location changed, so do your thing here...
  document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "none";
 })
};
```